# How to return DTO object from WCF C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, entity, dto

I have a wcf service, I want return a dto object, then I want consuming service from other app web ASP.net using WSDL reference service, but not work dto from wcf in dto client app.

And show this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClientApp.ClientWs.Client' to
>   'CoreApp.DTO.Client

And the dto "Client" is the same in both applications

DTO

```
public class Client
{

    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Sales> listSales { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        listSales = new List<Sales>();
    }
}
```

WCF service:

```
 public Client getClientByID(string id)
 {
        List<Sales> list = null;
        Client clientResponse = null;

        try
        {
            list = new List<Sales>();
            list = bll.getInstance.listSales(id);
            clientResponse = new Client();
            clientResponse.status = "ok";
            clientResponse.message = "success";
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                clientResponse.listSales.Add(item);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clientResponse = new Client();
            clientResponse.status = "error";
            clientResponse.message = ex.Message;
        }

        return clientResponse;
  }
```

Method app client:

```
 public static List<Sales> getByIdWebService(string id)
 {


       List<Sales> list = null;
        ClientWs.ClientWsClient ws = new ClientWs.ClientWsClient;

       Client response = new Client();
       response = ws.getClientByID(id); //show error 

        if (response.status == "error")
        {
            throw new Exception(response.message);
        }
        else
        {
            list = new List<Sales>();
            list = response.listSales();
        }

   }
```

Comment: Can you show your `Sales` Class property here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to add the WCF service to the web app as a WSDL web reference?
If you add it as a true service reference, you can elect the option to re-use the other assemblies, including your DTOs.

*Edit: there is probably a way to do the same thing for WSDL references, but it is probably not as straightforward... at least, that's my excuse for not knowing it :)*

First of all, you probably want to mark your DTO classes and members as serializable with the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` decorators:

```
namespace DtoClassLib
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Sales
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Client
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Sales> listSales { get; set; }

        public Client()
        {
            listSales = new List<Sales>();
        }
    }
}
```

When adding the reference to the WCF service, select the "Add Service Reference" option, Advanced settings, select the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" checkbox, and specifically add the DTO assembly used by both the WCF service and the web app:

[image: WCF Reuse Assemblies]

Take care to properly wrap your service proxies in `using` or try-finally blocks:

```
public static List<Sales> getByIdWebService( string id )
{
    List<Sales> list = null;

    using ( WcfSvcRefAsWsdl.ClientWsClient wsdlClient = new WcfSvcRefAsWsdl.ClientWsClient() )
    {
        // The following will not compile
        // DtoClassLib.Client returnClient = wsdlClient.getClientByID( id );
    }

    using ( WcfSvcRef.ClientWsClient wcfClient = new WcfSvcRef.ClientWsClient() )
    {
        // Joy!  \o/
        DtoClassLib.Client client = wcfClient.getClientByID( id );
        list = client.listSales;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can overcome this issue by changing your proxy class.

- It will generate automatically, when you adding service reference
- It has all types and methods that your are using in client app